# UICollectionView in UITableViewCell - touches only received in a portion of view

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm having an issue receiving touches in UICollectionViews contained within UITableViewCells. The desired effect is a UITableView with `n` rows of horizontally scrolling UICollectionViews. The view is displaying correctly but the collection views only receive touches in the top 44px. I imagine that the table view is still in the process of initialization when the collection views are created and that the collection views are using UITableView's default cell height when setting up their gesture recognizers. Relevant code is below.

In my UITableViewCell subclass, I create a container view for the UICollectionView:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    if (!_collectionViewContainer) {
        _collectionViewContainer = [[CVTCollectionViewContainer alloc] init];
        _collectionViewContainer.frame = self.bounds;
        [self.contentView addSubview:_collectionViewContainer];
    };
}
```

In my container view, I instantiate a UICollectionView:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];

    if (!self.collectionView) {

        UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
        self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
        self.collectionView.delegate = self;
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
        self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        flowLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
        flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(130.0, 130.0);
        [_collectionView registerClass:[CVTCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Collection view cell"];
        [self addSubview:self.collectionView];
    }
}
```

There's nothing interesting in my UITableViewController, just that I return 200 in tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:

It occurred to me that the layoutSubviews method of my UITableViewCell subclass may be the wrong place for initialization of the 'container' view for my UICollectionView. But, when I `NSLog(@"cell: %@", self);` in layoutSubviews, the cell's frame shows the desired height (200). Still, I have a feeling that I am doing my setup for the collection view too early, but I can't think of where else I might perform this work.

So, the gist: how can I add a UICollectionView to a UITableViewCell and make sure that the UICollectionView's gesture recognizers respond in the entirety of the collection view, rather than just the top 44 px?

Thanks in advance, as always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit of a facepalm here, I was using a UITableViewController that was created in storyboard but mostly configured in code. In storyboard, I had not set the row height of the table view, so it was still at the default 44 px. Of course, the table view looked at IB for its initial config so, although `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` was being called and the cells were displaying correctly, the initial height set in IB was affecting how the cell's subviews were created.